# Why java class fields (and event handler fields) will not initialize in android dialog and custom views?

Tags: java, android, field, android-custom-view, android-dialog

I made a lot of dialog in android by java like below:

```
public class MyComponent extends LinearLayout {

   // constructors that will call InitializeComponent after inflate layout

    private View.OnClickListener PersistButton_OnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PersistRest();
        }
    };

    private void PersistRest() {
        int selectedIndex = RestTimePicker().getValue() - 1;
        long selectedTimeSpan = predefinedDurationValues[selectedIndex];
        SecretaryManagerUtility.RegisterRestByDuration("", SecretaryManagerUtility.Me(), System.currentTimeMillis(), selectedTimeSpan);
    }

    @Override
    protected void InitializeComponents() {    
        PersistButton().setOnClickListener(PersistButton_OnClickListener);
        super.InitializeComponents();
    }


    private Button m_PersistButton;

    protected Button PersistButton(){
        if(m_PersistButton == null)
            m_PersistButton = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.PersistButton);
        return m_PersistButton; 
    }
}
```

Problem is method `PersistButton_OnClickListener.onClick` never called after clicking button `PersistButton`

but if I change onClick assignment to below code, everything works fine:

```
    PersistButton().setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PersistRest();
        }
    });
```

why?
This problem happens only in android dialog and android custom views

Comment: FYI: Pascal casing in Java makes reading your code more difficult. Please consider sticking with the Java conventions.

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer, but apologize me for incorrect question. InitializeLayout() method will be called in constructor (I use custom tool to generate view objects from xml)

the problem is java fields will NOT initialize before calling to super() constructor, and then, fields are null when InitializeLayout() has been called